# GDAL change spatial resolution via function

Tags: resolution

i have an geoTIFF with 30 arc Seconds spatial resolution. I would like to change its spatial resolution to 60 arc Seconds. Can i use an gdal function to change the 30 arc Seconds resolution to 60 arc seconds?

Comment: Have you looked into resampling with gdalwarp?

Comment: The use of gdal_translate -outsize 50% 50% gets the job done perfect, topic can be closed

Answer (score 1):

Since GDAL 2.1 most of command line utilities were converted to library calls. So you can execute GDALTranslate with appropriate parameters (see. https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/2.1/gdal/apps/gdal_utils.h#L74)

Support of this methods is also in bindings.

Example of usage: https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/2.1/autotest/cpp/test_gdal.cpp#L242-L262